# Why can't I read the variable in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to access a variable in the render method. I have declared the variable outside the render function but inside the class definition. For some reason I cannot access the variable. It works if I declare the variable inside the render function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
let a = "Random"
render() {

return (
  <View>
    <Text>{a}</Text>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: did you try `this.a`?

Comment: This is not valid syntax. You cannot put a variable declaration there.

Comment: You need to read up on Javascript's `class` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set variable in state and access that using `this` keyword `this.state.a` or you have to define it before your class as a `constant` or `let` or `var`.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
    const a="random";

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {

   constructor (props){
      super (props);
        this.state={
              let a = "Random"
        }
   }

        render() {
            let {a}=this.state;

            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{a}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: state is not needed though

Comment: State shouldn't be necessary. Also `this.state={let a = "Random"}` is a) not valid syntax and b) not valid at this position.

Comment: Yes, inside the constructor `this.state = {...}` is valid. However, `this.state={let a = "Random"} ` is still not valid. Please [edit] your answer to provide valid code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your variable declaration into the render method. The declaration won't work otherwise.

```
render() {
    const a = "Random";
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{a}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```